# Use configuration file to initialize a node_modules library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, configuration, node-modules

I made a react component library that I would like to use in multiple projects.
I need to use different variables depending on the environments, for this reason I was thinking of using an initialization file (eg: `my-library.init.js`) in the host app that exports a `config` variable, but I don't know how to make the library read this variable from host app.
the file should look like this:

```js
export const config = {
  envs: {
    S3_URL: 'https://my.dev.url.org'
    ENV: 'dev'
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated
Tahnk you

Comment: Hi are you able to figure this out? I need to implement same thing for one of my custom built library